# how to change title bar icon in flutter desktop

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows, flutter-macos-2.0.0-stable

this is how I change the title but can't change the icon.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux || Platform.isMacOS) {
    setWindowTitle('Title');
    // setWindowMinSize(const Size(20, 20));
    setWindowMaxSize(Size.infinite);
  }
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the default Icon for a flutter desktop application, you have to replace

- For Windows `windows/runner/resources/app_icon.ico`
- For MacOS `macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/app_icon_*.png`

Note that there are tools that can generate the iconset for macos, for example this [online tool](https://appicon.co/).

Answer (score 2):

Title is plateform dependant. for Window have a look in main.cpp

```
  FlutterWindow window(&run_loop, project);
  Win32Window::Point origin(10, 10);
  Win32Window::Size size(1280, 720);
  if (!window.CreateAndShow(L"Your title", origin, size)) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
```

Title is hard coded !

---

Comment: I want to change the icon, not the title. can u tell me how can I change icon in the title bar